# Best way to host a single JSON file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hosting, cloudflare

I've built a RoR application and there is a part of it that creates a JSON file and can send it to a server. My question is what is the best way to host this file so it can be retrieved fast from any country and will not fall over under large amounts of. I've looked into a CDN like cloudflare but am not sure that is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload your file on Amazon S3 then configure Amazon Cloudfont for CDN

Here is detailed [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html)

Alternately you can use your own server and setup Cloudflare on top of it, it has good caching capabilities.